# How can we call the `cy:test-flight` given in package.json from `.cirlceci/config.yml` file

Tags: cypress, circleci

For my cypress tests in my `Circleci` CI/CD pipeline, how can I call the command `cy:test-flight` given under scripts section in Package.json file from `.cirlceci/config.yml`. Also I would like to set following parameters `record true` and parallel set to 3. Could someone please advise on how to achieve this using `.cirlceci/config.yml`

Package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "cy:run": "cypress run",
    "get-token-flight": "node get-token.js && mv tokenData.json cypress/fixtures && mv cookies.json cypress/fixtures",
    "cy:open:flight": "npm run get-token-flight && cypress open",
    "cy:test-flight": "set CYPRESS_RETRIES=2 && npm run get-token-flight && cypress run --record --key <key-here> cypress --env configFile=flight-app --browser chrome"
  }
```

.cirlceci/config.yml

```
version: 2.1
orbs:
  cypress: cypress-io/cypress@1
workflows:
  build:
    jobs:
      - cypress/install
      - cypress/run
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example of my `circle.yml`:

```
version: 2.1
jobs:
  test:
    docker:
    - image: cypress/base:10
    steps:
    - checkout
    - restore_cache:
        keys:
        - cache-{{ arch }}-{{ .Branch }}-{{ checksum "package.json" }}
    - run:
        name: Yarn install
        command: yarn install --frozen-lockfile
    - save_cache:
        key: cache-{{ arch }}-{{ .Branch }}-{{ checksum "package.json" }}
        paths:
        - ~/.cache
    - run:
        command: yarn lint
    - run:
        command: yarn test
    - run:
        command: yarn test-e2e
    - run:
        command: yarn run semantic-release
workflows:
  build:
    jobs:
    - test
  version: 2
```

So you can replace `yarn test-e2e` with `npm run cy:test-flight` for example

Also,  here's a bunch of examples that utilize the cypress orb https://github.com/cypress-io/circleci-orb/blob/master/docs/examples.md#simple

Comment: Thank you ..I don't have a branch version ..so should I add Master instead of branch..in the following  `- cache-{{ arch }}-{{ .Master}}-{{ checksum "package.json" }}` How do we add `record` and `parrallel =3` in the config.yml

Comment: here's a bunch of examples that utilize the cypress orb https://github.com/cypress-io/circleci-orb/blob/master/docs/examples.md#simple